# Clicking on Admin Panel Side menu refreshes page instead of expanding the menu item

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I am facing a weird issue with [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/) admin panel template which is I am using for my Angular 11 app. Its all loading the menu item. No issue with it. But when clicking an item refreshes the page instead of expanding the group.

Here is how it looks

[image]

When I clicking on Data Reconciliation for example, it reloads the page again. Then when I click it again, it expands the group

Here is the markup

```
 <nav class="mt-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
    <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
         with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
    <li class="nav-item menu-open">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        <p>
          Dashboard
          <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </p>
      </a>
      <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
            <p>
              Data Reconciliation
              <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
              <span class="badge badge-info right">6</span>
            </p>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html" class="nav-link">
                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                <p>Top Navigation</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html" class="nav-link">
                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                <p>Top Navigation</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-header">Reports</li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-copy"></i>
            <p>
              Layout Options
              <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
              <span class="badge badge-info right">6</span>
            </p>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html" class="nav-link">
                <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                <p>Top Navigation</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./index3.html" class="nav-link">
            <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
            <p>Dashboard v3</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

What could be the reason? Is this issue have any connection with Angular?

Comment: try throwing an `event.preventDefault()` on the click event of anchor tags? If you can replicate the problem in a sandbox it might make it easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry, that didnt make any difference

Answer (score 1):

Replace ALL

```
href="#"
```

by

```
[routerLink]=""
```

This should works.

Answer (score 0):

In the `imports` section add:

```
declare var $: any;
```

In `ngOnInit` section:

```
$('[data-widget="treeview"]').Treeview('init');
```

inside the `sidebar` component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).